# Cron not work - exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Mage registry key "_singleton/admin/session" already exists'

Tags: magento, cron

Before it was missed or skipped.

Now it only stays in pending, when I added my email I started to see the problem, and not think one the solution.

```
cpanel cron = 
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash /home/adesi075/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode always
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash /home/adesi075/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode default
```

**I set up to send me an email**

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Mage registry key "_singleton/admin/session" already exists' in /home/adesi075/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/adesi075/public_html/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /home/adesi075/public_html/app/Mage.php(477): Mage::register('_singleton/admi...', Object(Mage_Admin_Model_Session))
#2 /home/adesi075/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(560): Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')
#3 /home/adesi075/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(316): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->_beforeSave()
#4 /home/adesi075/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/ScheduleManager.php(43): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#5 /home/adesi075/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(34): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_ScheduleManager->skipMissedSchedules()
#6 /home/adesi075/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /home/adesi075/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#8 /home/adesi075/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#9 /home/adesi075/public_html/shell/scheduler.php(519): Mage::dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#10 /home/adesi075/public_html/shell/scheduler.php(37): Aoe_Scheduler_Shell_Scheduler->cronAction()
#11 /home/adesi075/public_html/shell/scheduler.php(545): Aoe_Scheduler_Shell_Scheduler->run()
#12 {main}Set-Cookie: adminhtml=92f4f6e5b55a55a7a99d040eaa2d4e2c; expires=Tue, 21-Feb-2017 17:55:02 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: @RobbieAverill With or without cache, with or without compilation, it's the same way

Comment: It was 1.9.2.4 I went to 1.9.3.2 and it continues the same way